# Correct way to find if a username exists if I type it in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

I have a `.htaccess` file that replaces `profile.php` in the URL. For example, instead of `example.com/profile.php` it becomes `example.com/JohnDoe123` and it still displays the user's profile. If you type an invalid username you should get a message saying the user doesn't exist. After many attempts to do this right, I am still left with no results. I tried looking up answers, asking in different ways, but have not found a correct answer (although everyone's efforts are appreciated greatly). I finally wrote this code and I would like some feedback to see if it's correct. Although, I'm getting the error `Call to undefined method mysqli::execute()`.

```
try{

$validuser = false;

$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   ''; 
$dbname =   'db';
$con    =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

if( !empty( $_GET['username'] ) ){

    $username = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


    $sql='select * from users where username=?';
    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        /* run the query to check username */

        /* Bind parameters to the placeholders */
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );

        /* execute */
        $result = $con->execute();

        if( $result ){

            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();

            $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            $validuser = ( $rows == 1 ) ? true : false;

            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            throw new Exception('Query failed');
        }

    } else {
        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement');
    }
}




if( $validuser ){
    /* display user profile */
    echo "<h1>User is real.</h1>";
} else {
    /* display message - user not found etc */
    echo "<h1>User is not real.</h1>";
}
```

EDIT: .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: `$result = $con->execute();` should be `$result = $stmt->execute();`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul is correct and you should also check if connection was successful before using `$con` object. [Check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *, COUNT(ID) from users where username=?` is the query that you are looking for.

Just fetch `COUNT(ID)` and see if there is any records turning with that specific username.

Pseudo:

```
if (COUNT(ID)>0){
//show profile 
} else {
//show error
}
```